# How to edit multiple cells in JavaFX TableView?

Tags: java, tableview, javafx-8, edit, uitableview

I have a **JavaFX** TableView with some columns and some rows. Each column has a custom TableCell to be edited, for example: some columns use text fields, some others use check boxes, choice boxes and so on.

What I want is to edit several cells (**simultaneously**) in the same column by doing the following:

1. Select some rows in the TableView.
2. Click on a cell using the right mouse button.
3. A context menu is shown with the option "Edit All"; choose it.
4. Somehow I edit one of those cells and every cell in the same column whose row is selected commits the same value.

What I want to know is whether it is possible for every cell to “commitEdit” the same value. I cannot find the way of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would not use the table cell as an editor for this, but open a popup instead with the appropriate control. Then just update the items in the model directly.

Comment: I ended up doing it that way, thanks.